# ¿Como obtengo el valor de una celda en una tabla HTML?

Tags: javascript, web

Hola a todos tengo un pequeño problema que no he podido resolver y acudo a su gran ayuda.

Necesito obtener un dato de las filas de una tabla para eso recorro la tabla
y comienzo a leer las celdas donde esta el dato pero no puedo obtenerlo.

He probado con `getAttribute("value")`, `.value`, `innerText` y `innerHTML`, nada me da el resultado, todo me dice `"of undefined"`.

```
function Proceso(){
var table = document.getElementById("tablaModificacion");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
console.log(rows.length);
for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    // var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td").getAttribute("value");
    var cells = document.getElementById("tablaModificacion").rows[i].cells[0];
    console.log(cells);
    console.log(usuario);
    // limpiaDerechos(cells[0].innerHTML);
    // IgualaDerechos(cells[0].innerHTML, usuario);
};
}
```

Se que tengo el dato por que cuando imprimo por consola me da el HTML correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres almacenar ese valor o qué deseas hacer con el después, no termina de quedar claro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no queda muy claro cual es tu necesidad, si quieres sacar todos los valores de las celdas, tu función Proceso() debería de ser así.

```
function Proceso(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tablaModificacion");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      console.log(table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por tu respuesta me sirvió de mucho.

Comment: Mi necesidad era obtener una sola celda de todas filas...

Answer (score 0):

¿No es mas fácil que le asignes una clase a tus celdas y con `jquery` recorras esas celdas a través de un `each`?

Si aun deseas hacerlo de esa manera creo que necesitas colocarle al final la palabra reservada `values`

```
var cells = document.getElementById("tablaModificacion").rows[i].cells[0].values;
```